# Cannot save as jpg after update

Tags: jpg

I am using the latest version of Photoshop.

For months and months I have been able to save my work as a JPG with no issues at all.

An update was performed this morning, and now it won't let me save as JPEG.

When I adjust the colour and the bit size etc., still nothing works. All my images (always have been) are A4 2480×3508 px.

I have been using frame mock-ups with my A4 images for months and this has only started happening today. Please help, I need this for my business.

Only options I have are PSD, PSB or TIFF. My file is only A4 size, so it's not because it's too big.

Please help.

Comment: This really is a rather urgent support question for Adobe

Comment: Make sure your image is in RGB colour mode, 8bit.

Comment: And does not have layers.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has made changes to the Save dialog.
You now need to choose “Save a copy” to save as JPG.

See https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-images.html

Comment: OMG you're right. I will never understand why Adobe tries to fix stuff which doesn't need fixing.

Comment: Thank you that worked! what a stupid update after all these years.

Answer (score 0):

It can be very confusing at first. You can choose *Save A Copy* from the File listing or use **Cntrl-Alt-S**, A box shows up saying *Save on your computer or to cloud document'*. Click the left *Save a copy* option. That is when the full list of Save options/formats is shown to select from. (For anyone else who gets updated from a pre-2020 version.)